# shell script to display the calendar of the current month with current date replace by *

Tags: shell, unix

I want the result to like this:

```
May 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
4   5  *  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31
```

I am able to extract the date using `date |cut -d' ' -f4`

but when i execute the command, `cal|sed "s/date|cut -d' ' -f4/*/"`

there is no change the calender output.

can some one tell me where am I going wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: Your result calender does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `data|cut -d' ' -f4` as a single script and using a word boundary around the selection you select that particular date.

```
cal|sed -r "s/\b$(date|cut -d' ' -f4)\b/*/"
```

Here putting `$(date|cut -d' ' -f4)` will be run as a script and the output will be used in `sed` selection:

```
cal|sed -r "s/\bOUTPUT\b/*/"
```

Using `\b` is important since it indicates as word boundary. Else, for current date (say 5), all occurrence of `5` would be replaced with `*`.

Output:

```
     July 2015        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 *  6  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$(...)` around your `date|cut -d' ' -f4` part so it is executed as a script:

`cal|sed "s/$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4)/*/"`

Update:
Re-reading your question I'm not completely sure if you want to replace the current date with `*` or add a `*` to the current date. For the latter, you can use the `&` character to use the pattern you're looking for in the replacement (so you can add * instead of only replacing):

`cal|sed "s/$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4)/*/"`

You can find a lot of info on sed by following [this link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).